# Can you run a python program on a HTML webpage?

Tags: python, html

I am using HTML to create a basic webpage and would like to run one of my python programs on it, is this possible?

Comment: That really depends on what exactly you mean by "run one of my python programs on it".

Comment: Web browsers do not support Python, so you cannot use it the same way as, say, JavaScript. You can, however, use Python as a server-side language to generate some HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative:

Take a look at the **flask** library if you want to create websites and run code from it: http://flask.pocoo.org

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can use python for loop, using same way you can also import libraries

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Square</th>
  </tr>
  <% for i in range(10): %>
    <tr>
      <td><% print i %></td>
      <td><% print i**2 %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```